How to translate autotools (makefile) script into bazel script?
I am new to bazel. I have the below makefile, and I would like to translate it into a bazel BUILD file.  How can I do that?
XCP_SOURCE_SRCDIR = main.cc
XCP_SOURCE = $(addprefix $(top_builddir)/src/, $(XCP_SOURCE_SRCDIR))
XCP_HEADER := $(patsubst %.cc,%.xcp.h,$(XCP_SOURCE))
FNI_HEADER := $(patsubst %.cc,%.fni,$(XCP_SOURCE))
# calculate filename's hash code.
FILENAME_HASH_CALC = $(shell echo -n 0x; echo -n $(word 1, $(shell tmpfile=$(shell mktemp); echo -n $(1) > $$tmpfile;  cksfv -c $$tmpfile | tail -1 | awk '{print $$2}';  rm -f $$tmpfile &> /dev/null)))

# .xcp.h example:
#   #define this_file_id 0xEA17FC25
%.xcp.h : %.cc
    @echo -e "#define this_file_id $(call FILENAME_HASH_CALC,$<)\n" > $@
xcp: $(XCP_HEADER)

# .fni example: 
#       { 0xEA17FC25, "../src/main.cc" },
%.fni : %.cc
    @echo "{ $(call FILENAME_HASH_CALC,$<), \"$<\" }, " > $@


id_filename_table_dup.h: $(FNI_HEADER)
    cat $^ >> $@


The autotools script steps:

Get source list XCP_SOURCE_SRCDIR.
main.cc -> ../src/main.cc
main.cc -> main.xcp.h
main.cc -> main.fni
write "#define this_file_id 0xEA17FC25" -> main.xcp.h, 0xEA17FC25 is filename "main" hash code.
write "{ 0xEA17FC25, "../src/main.cc" }," -> main.fni
collect all *.fni into id_filename_table_dup.h

How would those steps be represented in a bazel BUILD file?
I have read the bazel manual and some articles, enough to realize that its design philosophy is very different from make's.  I'm unsure how to proceed.

That's a makefile, using features specific to GNU make. It does not appear to have any association with the Autotools, which are a separate thing.  Certainly Automake was not involved in creating the makefile presented.  Possibly it was generated from a template by Autoconf, but even if so, that does not appear to be relevant to the question. Tags edited.

You just rewrite the build steps using Bazel. Start with a tutorial on Bazel, then just start working on that project. Make sure you split the task in easy steps and put each into a separate commit, so you can retrace and re-evaluate your steps.
